# Short story in which a girl at a dinner party describes the end of the world by flooding

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, apocalypse

The story is about a guy at a dinner party who goes into the kitchen to get a cup of coffee and meets the daughter of the party hosts. He starts talking to her and she mentions she is working on a school assignment where she has to write about how the world will end. She tells him that she thinks the world will flood and goes into graphic detail. This unnerves him and he returns to the party where he tells the host he talked to the daughter to which the host states that she is an unusual girl.

Comment: Does it have any science-fiction or fantasy elements, could you edit to tell us about them.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I just remembered the name. It is **"[The Intoxicated](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63653)"** (1949) by Shirley Jackson.

From a Goodreads [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/4582412019):

> The intoxicated man that has attended a party goes to the kitchen to sober up, meeting the young girl and daughter of the host and chatting with her idly about her life, school etc. She makes a mention of her essay on The End of The World , and discusses her anxieties surrounding the future probing with questions the man whose carefree attitude starts to feel a bit threatened .
>
> The girl is in deep thoughts about the future and the world , the man is cheerful in ignorance, drunk and doesn't want to accept this metaphorical invitation to action and concern for the future.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until the question is 48 hours old before the site will let you do that.